# Flipped switch statements?

Tags: switch-statement, logic

Consider you have 10 boolean variables of which only one can be true at a time, and each time any one is 'switched on', all others must be 'turned off'. One of the problems that immediately arises is;

> How can you quickly test which variable is true without necessarily
>   having to linearly check all the variable states each time?

For this, I was thinking if it was possible to have something like:

```
switch(true)
{
   case boolean1:
       //do stuff
   ...
   //other variables
}
```

This looks like a bad way of testing for 10 different states of an object, but I think there're cases where this kind of feature may prove useful and would like to know if there's any programming language that supports this kind of feature?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a language feature that offers this behavior. But as an alternative, you could use the Command Pattern, in conjunction with a Priority Queue. This assumes that you would be able to prioritize what checks should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, when you have such [radio button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button) boolean values you use an integer to represent them:

```
+------------+---------+--------------------+
|   BINARY   | DECIMAL | BINARY-LOGARITHMIC |
+------------+---------+--------------------+
| 0000000001 |       1 |                  0 |
| 0000000010 |       2 |                  1 |
| 0000000100 |       4 |                  2 |
| 0000001000 |       8 |                  3 |
| 0000010000 |      16 |                  4 |
| 0000100000 |      32 |                  5 |
| 0001000000 |      64 |                  6 |
| 0010000000 |     128 |                  7 |
| 0100000000 |     256 |                  8 |
| 1000000000 |     512 |                  9 |
+------------+---------+--------------------+
```

Let's call the variable holding this boolean value `flag`. We can quickly jump to some code based on the `flag` by indexing a random access array of functions:

```js
var functions = [ function0
                , function1
                , function2
                , function3
                , function4
                , function5
                , function6
                , function7
                , function8
                , function9
                ];

functions[flag]();          // quick jump
```

However, you will have to pay for the function call overhead.

Comment: My thoughts as well, we simply have 10 different states which we can save as enums or whatever and do a direct test for the state, but in terms of error programming, where let's say you want to determine which of your objects has a particular state or something, won't this kind of feature be useful? For the most part, I think it can make for some kind of intelligent programming where internal program state can respond better to external conditions.

Comment: I am a functional programmer. Hence, I don't deal with implicit state. Thus, I have no idea what you are talking about.